# Angular 14 Sorting Elements in an Array by Date

Tags: .net, angular

in my Angualar 14 project, I am pulling a data from the database and assigning this data to the list, I have a createDatetime column in this data. When I save the data to the database, since I save 20 data at the same time, it only differs in milliseconds, so I cannot sort it from small to large, how can I sort this data from small to large?

```
shorted Code ;   const sortedList = this.measurementTable.productionTableDetails.sort((a, b) => {
      const dateA = new Date(a.createDateTime);
      const dateB = new Date(b.createDateTime);
      return Number(dateA) - Number(dateB);
    });   

dateFormat : "2023-02-15T17:00:44.0058977"
```

Comment: I assume it differs in microseconds - if they differed in milliseconds js date objects would have handled it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your standard javascript Date object doesn't hold precision lower than miliseconds, so the microseconds you provide will be trimmed. If you want to use dates with microseconds in js, you might want to use moment.js or luxon.js - perhaps they can provide such feature, but I haven't checked.

But your date format is ISO-8601 compliant (even though it uses microseconds instead of milliseconds, it's still technically standard-compliant as IIRC the standard doesn't provide forced precision, only guidelines).

Since ISO-8601 has all units sorted in descending order, and all values use descending order, it means you can safely use lexicographical order for the sorting. This means you can simply sort the strings and they will be ordered correctly.

If sorting is all that you're interested in, you can simply do something like:

```
const sortedList = this.measurementTable.productionTableDetails.sort((a, b) => {
    // Compare the strings using lexicographical sort, i.e. compare strings
    if (a.createDateTime < b.createDateTime) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    if (a.createDateTime > b.createDateTime) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your Date objects to a number explicitly. Try to use getTime()

```
const sortedList = this.measurementTable.productionTableDetails.sort((a, b) => {
      const dateA = new Date(a.createDateTime).getTime();
      const dateB = new Date(b.createDateTime).getTime();
      return dateA - dateB;
    });
```

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: This won't work, since js date objects don't store anything below milliseconds, so the microseconds used in the question will be trimmed.